# Sylius API request returns contents of hwi_oauth_security (/connect) route as response

Tags: api, rest, sylius

I tried to use the Sylius API by using [this guide](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/api/authorization.html).

Authorization seems okay because no 'bad request' errors occur.

If I try to fetch, for example, a list of all taxonomies, I'm getting a Sylius\Api\InvalidResponseFormatException because the API returns me the contents of the hwi_oauth_security (/connect) route. It's the one with the amazon/facebook/google login links.

I tried with the HttpFul library, and with [Lakions client](https://github.com/Lakion/sylius-api-php). Both same response. This is on Sylius 0.14. I tried this on a fresh install too, also same response.

Am I missing something here? I am trying to login with the admin user that was generated during install.

Comment: Are you using login credentials? (http auth)